# C# Combine Two Classes of Strings

Tags: c#, string, class

I have a class of three strings (`firstname`, `lastname`, `account`).
I have two lists of this class:

- the first list contains instances where `firstname` and `lastname` have values
- the second list contains instances where `lastname` and `account` have values

The unique identifier is `lastname`. How can I quickly add `account` values from the second list to the corresponding instances in the first list?

```
class MyClass
{
    public string firstName = "";
    public string lastName = "";
    public string account = ""
}

List<MyClass> list1; //This is populated from a csv and fills strings firtname and lastname
List<MyClass list2; // This is populated from a report and fills lastname and account
```

These two lists have the same information for `lastname` but not necesarily in the same order. I need to match on `lastname` and set `account` of the instances in `list1`.

Comment: `instance1.String3 = instance2.String3;`? I don't understand the question. Or are you talking about two _lists_ of those classes instead of two _instances_?

Comment: Sharing is caring. Share your code please.

Comment: Ouch. Ouch, my eyes hurt.

Comment: what is this i dont even

Comment: sorry, these are Lists

Comment: wow, -6, I'm kind of new to posting, sorry

Comment: Please read [ask]. Also, the code you've just posted won't work, `1` is not a valid identifier name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you clarified, try this:

```
foreach(MyClass c1 in list1)
{
    MyClass tmp = list2.FirstOrDefault(c2 => c1.lastname == c2.lastname);
    c1.account = tmp != null ? tmp.account : null; // or string.Empty if you like
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error for the ".account" it says "Syntax error, ':' expected"

Comment: So maybe you don't have c#6? I'll fix my answer for pre-c#6 version

Comment: @AWooster updated my answer (and fixed your question)

Comment: thanks! works great!

Comment: @AWooster you're welcome. Please put more effort in the way you ask the next time. SO users are quite fast in closing bad questions. And you may accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I know, trying to do too many things at work..  I usually am able to find my question already answered, just trying to juggle too many things left me thoughtless on how to even ask the question :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have appropriate getters and setters defined, and you wish to ensure they have the same unique identifier:

```
if (obj1.getString2().equals(obj2.getString2()) {
    obj1.setString3(obj2.getString3());
}
```

Surely?

You will have to be mindful of nulls here though. If obj1 is null or obj.getString2() is null, then you're going to hit a problem with a NullPointerException.